# Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter Please specify it explicitly

Tags: data-binding, vaadin, kotlin, type-inference

I'm trying to write a Vaadin application in Kotlin. For data binding, Vaadin 8 now provides a possibility for type safe data binding. In Kotlin I would have expected work like that:

```
class LoginModel {
    var username: String = ""
    var password: String = ""
}

class LoginView : FormLayout() {
  val name = TextField("name")
  val password = TextField("password")
  val loginButton = Button("login")

  init {
      val binder = Binder<LoginModel>()
      binder.forField(name).bind(
          { it.username }, 
          { bean, value -> bean.username = value })

     //... 
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error message here:

```
Error:(23, 31) Kotlin: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter BEAN in fun <BEAN : Any!, TARGET : Any!, BEAN : Any!> Binder.BindingBuilder<BEAN#1 (type parameter of bind), TARGET>.bind(p0: ((BEAN#1!) -> TARGET!)!, p1: ((BEAN#1!, TARGET!) -> Unit)!): Binder.Binding<BEAN#1!, TARGET!>!
Please specify it explicitly.
```

I tried by explicit specifying the type parameters:

```
binder.forField(name).bind<LoginView, String, LoginView>(
    { it.username }, 
    { bean, value -> bean.username = value })
```

but that leads to the error message (and other sytax errors, so I did not follow that approach)

```
Error:(23, 35) Kotlin: No type arguments expected for fun bind(p0: ValueProvider<LoginModel!, String!>!, p1: Setter<LoginModel!, String!>!): Binder.Binding<LoginModel!, String!>! defined in com.vaadin.data.Binder.BindingBuilder
```

My second approach was trying to pass the Kotlin property accessors directly, but the error message was the same as the first one:

```
binder.forField(name).bind(LoginModel::username.getter, LoginModel::username.setter)
```

The last approeach was trying to use an extension method and make everything as explicit as possible:

```
fun <BEAN, TARGET> Binder.BindingBuilder<BEAN, TARGET>.bind(property: KMutableProperty1<BEAN, TARGET>) {

    fun set(bean: BEAN): TARGET = property.get(bean)
    fun get(bean: BEAN, value: TARGET): Unit = property.set(bean, value)
    this.bind(::set, ::get)
}
```

But it leads still to the same error message as the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried your example and it compiles just fine with my Intellij 2017.1.4 and Kotlin 1.1.2-5. Probably you have discovered a bug in older version of a Kotlin plugin?

The method `bind` takes no generic parameters so it cannot be generified. The `forField` method takes one generic parameter, so perhaps you can try

```
    binder.forField<String>(name).bind(
            { it.username },
            { bean, value -> bean.username = value })
```

But first, please make sure that you have the newest version of the Kotlin plugin, and/or perhaps try it out with Intellij Community Edition.

However, I urge you to use `bind(String)` since other bind methods won't work with JSR303 validations. You can also define the following extension method:

```
fun <BEAN, FIELDVALUE> Binder.BindingBuilder<BEAN, FIELDVALUE>.bind(prop: KMutableProperty1<BEAN, FIELDVALUE?>): Binder.Binding<BEAN, FIELDVALUE> =
        bind(prop.name)
```

And call it as follows from your code `binder.forField(name).bind(LoginModel::username)`. Please see here for more examples: https://github.com/mvysny/karibu-dsl/blob/master/example-v8/src/main/kotlin/com/github/vok/karibudsl/example/form/FormView.kt

Comment: I had no issues on Kotlin 1.1.2-5 as well.

Answer (score 2):

You must be using API level 26+. This version has changed the signature of View.findViewById() - see here https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#fvbi-signature

The result of findViewById is ambiguous, you need to supply the type:

For example:

```
val myTextView = findViewById(R.id.list) as TextView
```

becomes

```
val myTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.myTextView)
```

Comment: The question was related to Vaadin, it is not related to Android at all.

Answer (score 0):

Since your model is fairly simple, you can complete the binding by connecting to the property with the given name via the [`Binder#bind(String propertyName)`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.6/com/vaadin/data/Binder.BindingBuilder.html#bind-java.lang.String-) method

```
val binder = Binder<LoginModel>()
binder.forField(name).bind("username");
```

Comment: That would work, but I'd like to use the type safe data binding and understand what exactly the problem with the type inference is.

Comment: This is actually a good advice, for the following reason: if you ever try to use BeanValidationBinder with JSR-303 validations with the `bind(ValueProvider, Setter)` method, it will skip the JSR-303 validations! You actually need to use `bind(String)` so that the validation annotations can be picked from the field itself.

Comment: @MartinVysny I agree.  However, the the OP wants to do it kotlin style. And I can appreciate that.

Comment: @petey I agree. That's why I'm not using `bind(String)` directly; but instead I'm using the abovementioned `bind(KMutableProperty1)`.