# Specifying the type explicitly in Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm creating the login page for my application and it gives me the error of `Cannot infer a type of this parameter. Please specify it explicitly`.

It gives error only within error and response. Any clue why it is like that?

```
var rq: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
            var sr = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener { response ->
                if(response.equals("0"))
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Login failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                else

                var i = Intent(this,LoggedinActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(i)
                Toast.makeText(this, "User created successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }, Response.ErrorListener {
                error ->
                Toast.makeText(this, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            })
            rq.add(sr)
```

The problem has been arised because I didn't check all the brackets correctly, thus if statements didn't work correctly and it was giving error because of that.

Sorry for the inconvenience. I wish you great week ahead. I checked the first answer as correct one.

Comment: You're lacking a [mcve] - specifically the rest of the error.

Comment: @Zoe, should I just copy and paste the whole code if the problem is only in this one? I don't think so.

Comment: I said *specifically the rest of the error*, the part pointing to lines. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44247827/6296561 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/44573118/6296561: there is more to the error.

Comment: Zoe, sorry for the inconvenience, firstly. I appreciate your effort for correcting and I edited the question and marked the first answer as correct one. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be your lack of brackets around your if and else.

Try this:

```
val rq: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val sr = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener { response ->
            if(response == "0") {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Login failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else {
                val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(i)
                Toast.makeText(this, "User created successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }, Response.ErrorListener {
            error ->
            Toast.makeText(this, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })
        rq.add(sr)
```

Comment: It 100% makes a difference. If you don't scope your `if` or `else` statements then it will only execute the first statement. I tried your block of code and it wouldn't compile until I put brackets around them.

Comment: `if(condition) statement` is perfectly valid, the issue is the else statement specifically, because it uses several lines. But that isn't the *only* issue with the code, and therefore does not fix it alone.

Comment: You were right, mate. Sorry for the inconvenience, your answer was correct and I marked it as correct one.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` should refer to activity context otherwise the code believes that it is the `Response.Listener` additionally as mentioned by [user8159708](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54722773/6296561) you need the brackets, at least to the `else` statement.

```
val rq: RequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val sr = StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener { response ->
            if(response == "0") {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Login failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
            else {
                val i = Intent(this@MainActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(i)
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "User created successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }, Response.ErrorListener {
            error ->
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, error.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })
        rq.add(sr)
```

**Edit:**

Proper syntax in kotlin is `this@MainActivity` according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617042/how-to-access-activity-this-in-kotlin)

Comment: @NijatMursali check my edit... the problem in you code is `this` you can simple remove all the logic with `this` and use a simple log message to test it... then find the way to add the proper `Context`. Without the rest class file we cannot guess where is the proper context.